# Laravel 5 MongoDB Library get records from specific date

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb library to work with mongodb, how can I query for records that belongs to a specific month? or records from today?

Answer (score 2):

There is a really nice date handling package in laravel called **[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)** that you could use with your queries. You could try using **`whereBetween`** if you want to query for records between a specific month, say April of 2015 based on a mongodb datetime field `created_at`:

```
$users = User::whereBetween('created_at', array(Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 4, 1), Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 4, 30)))->get();
```

Similarly, to get records from today, use Carbon's **[`startOfDay()`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/tests/StartEndOfTest.php)** property:

```
$dt = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$users = User::where('created_at', '>', $dt)->get();
```

Another approach would be to use **[Eloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#dates)** which allows you to work with Carbon/DateTime objects instead of MongoDate objects. Example inspired from the **[docs](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#dates)**:

```
<?php

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    /**
     * Collection for Model
     *
     * @var String
     */
    protected $collection = "users";

    /**
     * Connection for model
     *
     * @var type
     */
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    protected $dates = array('created_at');
}
```

Which allows you to execute queries like:

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '>', new DateTime('-1 day'))->get();
```

Or natively using MongoDate objects, you could try

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-04-01 00:00:00"));
$stop = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-04-30 00:00:00"));

$users = DB::collection('users')->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $stop))->get();
```

Comment: That's a great answer. but is there a way to execute something like MySQL: `where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') = '2015-05'` or something like that? i don't want to have hours glitch in the future and to use only days (or months)